# How to combine a global MobX store with local state in the component?

Tags: typescript, react-native, mobx, mobx-react-lite

I have the next component:

```
const App = observer(({injector}: Props) => {
  const preferences = injector.getPreferences().execute()
  const themeStore = useLocalStore(() => ({
    _theme:
      preferences.theme === ETheme.DARK
        ? CombinedDarkTheme
        : CombinedDefaultTheme,
    get theme(): ReactNativePaper.Theme & Theme {
      return this._theme
    },
    set theme(value: ReactNativePaper.Theme & Theme) {
      this._theme = value
    },
  }))
  const onThemeChange = React.useCallback(() => {
    const colorScheme = Appearance.getColorScheme()
    themeStore.theme =
      colorScheme === 'dark' ? CombinedDarkTheme : CombinedDefaultTheme
  }, [themeStore])
  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (preferences.theme === ETheme.SYSTEM) {
      const subscription = Appearance.addChangeListener(onThemeChange)
      return subscription.remove
    }
  }, [onThemeChange, preferences.theme])
  return (
    <PaperProvider theme={themeStore.theme}>
      <NavigationContainer theme={themeStore.theme}>
        // Some views
      </NavigationContainer>
    </PaperProvider>
  )
})
```

Global MobX store:

```
export default class PreferencesGateway implements IPreferencesGateway {
  _preferences: Preferences = {
    theme: ETheme.LIGHT,
    signedInUserId: null,
  }

  constructor(private _storage: IStorageGateway) {
    makeObservable(this, {
      _preferences: observable,
      preferences: computed,
      setPreferences: action,
    })
  }

  get preferences(): Preferences {
    return this._preferences
  }

  async setPreferences({
    theme,
    signedInUserId,
  }: PreferencesUpdate): Promise<void> {
    if (theme) this._preferences.theme = theme
    if (signedInUserId !== undefined)
      this._preferences.signedInUserId = signedInUserId
    await this.savePersistData()
  }

  async loadPersistData(): Promise<Preferences> {
    const prefs = await this._storage.get<Preferences>(STORAGE_KEY_PREFERENCES)
    if (prefs) this._preferences = prefs
    return this._preferences
  }

  async savePersistData(): Promise<void> {
    await this._storage.set(STORAGE_KEY_PREFERENCES, this._preferences)
  }
}
```

I need to `App` listened MobX global store (`preferences.theme`), the `ETheme` definition is below:

```
enum ETheme {
  DARK = 'DARK',
  LIGHT = 'LIGHT',
  SYSTEM = 'SYSTEM',
}
```

When the user sets `preference.theme` to `DARK` or `LIGHT`, the app just follows a simple expression:

```
theme = preferences.theme === ETheme.DARK ? ETheme.DARK : ETheme.LIGHT
```

However, when user sets `preference.theme` to `AUTO`, the app has to subscribe on `Appearance.addChangeListener()` and follows a system theme.

Unfortunately, my solution doesn't work correctly and leads to multiple changes when the user sets `SYSTEM`. I am a noobie in **React Native** and **MobX** and can't get an error reason but seems these stores conflict. I've also tried `useState` instead of `useLocalStore` but it just led to infinite redrawing.

[image: Screenshot]

How to fix it?

**P.S.** I feel that I've written a some bul****, and it can be simplified also.

**UPD**
I simplified `App` a little:

```
const App = observer(({injector}: Props) => {
  const preferences = injector.getPreferences().execute()
  const [systemTheme, setSystemTheme] = React.useState<
    ReactNativePaper.Theme & Theme
  >(
    Appearance.getColorScheme() === 'dark'
      ? CombinedDarkTheme
      : CombinedDefaultTheme,
  )
  const onThemeChange = React.useCallback(() => {
    const colorScheme = Appearance.getColorScheme()
    setSystemTheme(
      colorScheme === 'dark' ? CombinedDarkTheme : CombinedDefaultTheme,
    )
  }, [])
  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (preferences.theme === ETheme.SYSTEM) {
      const subscription = Appearance.addChangeListener(onThemeChange)
      return subscription.remove
    }
  }, [onThemeChange, preferences.theme])
  const localTheme =
    preferences.theme === ETheme.DARK ? CombinedDarkTheme : CombinedDefaultTheme
  const theme = preferences.theme === ETheme.SYSTEM ? systemTheme : localTheme
  return (
    <PaperProvider theme={theme}>
      <NavigationContainer theme={theme}>
        <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="SplashScreen">
          <Stack.Screen name="MainScreen" options={{headerShown: false}}>
            {props => <MainScreen injector={injector} {...props} />}
          </Stack.Screen>
          <Stack.Screen
            name="SettingsScreen"
            options={{
              header: props => <SimpleAppBar {...props} title="Settings" />,
            }}>
            {props => <SettingsScreen injector={injector} {...props} />}
          </Stack.Screen>
          <Stack.Screen
            name="SignInScreen"
            options={{
              header: props => <SimpleAppBar {...props} title="Account" />,
            }}>
            {props => <SignInScreen injector={injector} {...props} />}
          </Stack.Screen>
          <Stack.Screen
            name="SignUpScreen"
            options={{
              header: props => <SimpleAppBar {...props} title="New account" />,
            }}>
            {props => <SignUpScreen injector={injector} {...props} />}
          </Stack.Screen>
          <Stack.Screen name="SplashScreen" options={{headerShown: false}}>
            {props => <SplashScreen injector={injector} {...props} />}
          </Stack.Screen>
        </Stack.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
    </PaperProvider>
  )
})
```

However, I got a new error when I try to switch a theme from `SYSTEM` to `LIGHT` or `DARK`:

[image: Screenshot 2]

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I could fix all errors. Below is a working solution:

```
const App = observer(({injector}: Props) => {
  const preferences = injector.getPreferences().execute()
  const [systemTheme, setSystemTheme] = React.useState<
    ReactNativePaper.Theme & Theme
  >(
    Appearance.getColorScheme() === 'dark'
      ? CombinedDarkTheme
      : CombinedDefaultTheme,
  )
  const onThemeChange = React.useCallback(() => {
    const colorScheme = Appearance.getColorScheme()
    setSystemTheme(
      colorScheme === 'dark' ? CombinedDarkTheme : CombinedDefaultTheme,
    )
  }, [])
  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (preferences.theme === ETheme.SYSTEM) {
      const subscription = Appearance.addChangeListener(onThemeChange)
      return () => subscription.remove()
    }
  }, [onThemeChange, preferences.theme])
  const localTheme =
    preferences.theme === ETheme.DARK ? CombinedDarkTheme : CombinedDefaultTheme
  const theme = preferences.theme === ETheme.SYSTEM ? systemTheme : localTheme
  return (
    <PaperProvider theme={theme}>
      <NavigationContainer theme={theme}>
        // Some views
      </NavigationContainer>
    </PaperProvider>
  )
})
```

There were two fixed:

1. I returned a wrong callback to unsubscribe from events in `useEffect()`: I've changed `return subscription.remove` to `return () => subscription.remove()`, although I can't get a difference honestly but it works.
2. I stopped to re-assign a variable from global MobX store to `useLocalStore()` or `useState()` variables. Instead of this, I've replaced it by the next condition assignment.

   ```
   const localTheme =
   preferences.theme === ETheme.DARK ? CombinedDarkTheme : CombinedDefaultTheme
   const theme = preferences.theme === ETheme.SYSTEM ? systemTheme : localTheme
   ```

It is not related to my problem in the question but I've also notices a warning from **MobX** about my global store due to `loadPersistData` tried to modify data asynchronously, I fixed it rewriting `loadPersistData` a little:

```
async loadPersistData(): Promise<Preferences> {
  const prefs = await this._storage.get<Preferences>(STORAGE_KEY_PREFERENCES)
  if (prefs) {
    runInAction(() => {
      this._preferences = prefs
    })
  }
  return this._preferences
}
```